Containerized Spring boot application is unable to connect to database within container
I seem to be encountering an error within an application that I have created in changing it to be ran via docker.
I want to be able to stat the application from running docker compose so I created a compose file with the following:
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: dbcontainer
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 
      MYSQL_USER: amazing05
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: amazing05
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: amazing05
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - my_network
        
  springbootapplication:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

    environment:
      MYSQL_CONTAINER: dbcontainer
      MYSQL_USER: amazing05
    networks:
      - my_network
    restart: on-failure
    
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge 

Application properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_CONTAINER:localhost}:3306/mycontainerdb
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Before I run the compose command I do a maven install to generate the application jar as I created a DockerFile to be built.
Once the containers are spun up I am met with this error
springbootapplication-1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
springbootapplication-1  | 
springbootapplication-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

This means the spring boot application did not find the container to connect to, but if I am to comment out the spring boot application service and run manually it finds the container fine. Any help much appreciated
I have tried running the application through docker compose and produces the error above but when I run just the mysql container and run the spring boot application manually it finds it successfully.

have you tried checking if your database (int the container) is running? What does docker logs say for the mysql? Also this line ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d looks like it could be the part with mistake - you should prefer absolute paths

why do you have localhost in your connection string?

@Shadow from my understanding when you set up the application properties to allow env variables ${MYSQL_CONTAINER:localhost}. If nothing is passed in for "MYSQL_CONTAINER" then it defaults to use localhost

@JAsgarov for mounting volumes I don't think I can provide absolute paths and if I could I wouldnt personally as if it was to be deployed the path wouldnt exist.
In the dockerlogs everything comes back good and that it started successfully.

@DylanHayes that's gteat - if you do have a mysql running on localhost. But you don't...

Docker Compose's depends_on only ensures that the MySQL container starts before the Spring Boot application container. It does not ensure that MySQL is ready to accept connections. You need to add a wait mechanism to ensure that the Spring Boot application only starts after MySQL is fully up and ready.
So you should add a Healthcheck to MySQL Service to ensure that is fully up and running before the Spring Boot application attempts to connect.
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: dbcontainer
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mycontainerdb
      MYSQL_USER: amazing05
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: amazing05
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: amazing05
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - my_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
  
  springbootapplication:
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      MYSQL_CONTAINER: dbcontainer
      MYSQL_USER: amazing05
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: amazing05
    networks:
      - my_network
    restart: on-failure
    
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge 



that was a way of thinking I was through adding some sort of delay didn't know a health check can be used to act as a test + a delay. Thanks for the explanation of depends_on I took it that it had to wait for the service to be fully started.
This half fixed my issue as there was a typo on my end for the application properties but this definitely prevents the initial starting error if the DB is not up in time!
